# run jarfile in sh script - what path?

Tags: bash, jar

So I have made this simple java app which I want to run with a simple double-click that opens my terminal and run the code on a Mac.

I written a simple start.sh script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar monkeykingApplication.jar
```

But this gives me and error because the jar can not be located.
So what path do I need to set if run my start.sh script in the same folder as my jar file is?

Comment: the current directory `java -jar ./monkeykingApplication.jar`  You need the `./` Otherwise you need the absolute path.

Comment: Still getting: `Error: Unable to access jarfile ./monkeykingApplication.jar` .. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the application executable? try the absolute path also.

Comment: Yes, it works if I CD my way to the path

Comment: `java -jar /path/to/monkeykingapplication` or If you wan the cd, try a subshell `(cd /path/to/the/monkeyKingApplication || exit; java -jar monkeykingApplication.jar)`

Comment: @Jetchisel the problem is I don't have the path if I send the application to a friend

Comment: I don't follow, you can cd your way to the application but you don't have the path?

Comment: I know the path on my own machine, but not on my friends.  Just for proofing that the jar is executable

Comment: that's where the PATH comes in.

Comment: @PeterHoldensgaard : If it works if you cd to your directory and execute it, your friend can do the same on his machine. After all, your friend wil hopefully know into which directory he places your application.

Answer (score 0):

Your example uses `sh` as shell, but you are tagging your question as *bash*, so I take the liberty to propose a bash solution:

Since you are delivering your jar together with a bash starter script, I would require that the starter script and the jar be installed by the user in the same directory. In your starter script, you can then find your own location, and use this information to locate the jar. How to find this location, has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/how-to-get-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within-the-script-itself). Using one of the answers in that page, you could do a:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Find your own location
install_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
# Invoke the jar
java -jar "$install_dir/monkeykingApplication.jar"
```

Most likely, the user will add the directory of the starter script to their PATH variable, but this is his/her own decision, and you don't have to care about this.